# Left recursive removal

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm learning about using ANTLR and have just end up this wired problem. I read many article but still stuck with this problem. Please help me.

```
expr: expr '+' INT| index;
index: expr '[' expr ']';
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your whole grammar for the parser and the lexer.

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100729/antlr4-left-recursive-error/47104644#47104644).